# .Net 3.5 Chart Controls Exception

Tags: .net, .net-3.5

I am using the new [free .net chart controls](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/24/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt.aspx) and they appear to work fine when I run the project up in visual studio, but when hitting the same via IIS I get and exception:

```
[HttpException (0x80004005): No http handler was found for request type 'GET']
   System.Web.HttpApplication.MapIntegratedHttpHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath path, String pathTranslated, Boolean useAppConfig, Boolean convertNativeStaticFileModule) +529
   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(String path, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm) +947

[HttpException (0x80004005): Error executing child request for ChartImg.axd.]
   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(String path, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm) +4120098
   System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler.EnsureInitialized(Boolean hardCheck) +266
   System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart.GetImageStorageMode() +25
   System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +133
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +240
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +240
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +253
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.Render(HtmlTextWriter output) +87
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +53
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +240
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +240
   System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +38
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4240
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution (sort of)

Solution:  It looks like I had the httpHandler correct in the web.config, but I was missing a hander and a appSetting (detailed in second post [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/MSWinWebChart/thread/1dc4b352-c9a5-49dc-8f35-9b176509faa1/)).  Once I got those sorted out it works fine.

Missing Point: Just not sure why that WOULD work when running it with visual studio.  Figure without those setting is should have failed in both environments (visual studio and iis).  Curious.

Thanks for everyone's help in pointing in some good directions.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried publishing a clean version of your project to IIS, as it seems you are missing the handler which deals with the chart image generation.

Comment: the IIS is pointing to the same location as the development area

Comment: tried a clean publish to a clean folder and repointed IIS, same issue persists - any other thoughts?

Comment: What are your permissions on the folder, have you allowed Write permissions and also, have you chose the charting contorl to save to file?

Comment: permissions seem fine ... it is odd as it works in development (i.e. when I run the project), but when hitting via IIS I get the above error

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your IIS is setup not to handle GET verbs. To check in IIS, then go to the site, then click Handler Mappings, find the .aspx handler, click request restrictions, then verbs.

If could also be something in between - like the IIS url scan.

Comment: it looks like it handles get ... i've not done anything special when setting up IIS - straight out of the box

Answer (score 1):

Are you using IIS 7? I had the same problem with IIS 7 and I switched the "Managed Pipeline Mode" to Classic in the Application Pool.

Comment: where did you find this little gem?